# Play 2.7 Migrating from Play 2.6 - Issue with Cache (Writing a Block Issue with getOrElseUpdate)

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am upgrading my application from Play 2.6 to Play 2.7.
    Build.sbt:  libraryDependencies= ehcache

With Play 2.6, the following Code is currently working

```
 public static Company getCompany() {
        Company company = cache.getOrElse(session("userSchema") + "c",   
    () -> {
            return overrideCompanyCache();
        }, 300);
        if (company != null) {
        }
    return company;

    }
```

getOrElse is Deprecated.

With Play 2.7:

```
  @NamedCache("session-cache")
    public static AsyncCacheApi cache;

    @Inject
    CacheController(AsyncCacheApi cache) {
        CacheController.cache = cache;
    }
```

I am trying to update the code as below:

```
  public static Company getCompany(){
        Company company=cache.getOrElseUpdate(session("user")+"c",

          ,3000);
    }
```

**However, I am not able to write a Block, as specified by getOrElseUpdate.**

Thanks in advance.